# Synchronous generator in asyncio

Tags: async-await, python-asyncio, concurrent.futures

I have the following scenario:

1. I have a blocking, synchronous generator
2. I have an non-blocking, async function

I would like to run blocking generator (executed in a `ThreadPool`) and the `async` function on the event loop. How do I achieve this?

The following function simply prints the output from the generator, not from `sleep` function.

Thanks!

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

import numpy as np
import asyncio
import time


def f():
    while True:
        r = np.random.randint(0, 3)
        time.sleep(r)
        yield r


async def gen():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
    gen = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, f)
    for item in gen:
        print(item)
        print('Inside generator')


async def sleep():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print('Inside async sleep')


async def combine():
    await asyncio.gather(sleep(), gen())


def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(combine())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`run_in_executor` doesn't work on generators because it is designed for blocking functions. While a generator is a valid function, it returns immediately when called, providing an object that the caller is supposed to exhaust through repeated invocations of `next`. (This is what Python's `for` loop does under the hood.) To use a blocking generator from async code, you have two choices:

- wrap each *step* of the iteration (each individual call to `next`) in a separate call to `run_in_executor`, or
- start a `for` loop in a separate thread and use a queue to transfer the objects to an async consumer.

Either approach can be abstracted into a function that accepts an iterator and returns an equivalent async iterator. This is an implementation of the second approach:

```py
import asyncio, threading

def async_wrap_iter(it):
    """Wrap blocking iterator into an asynchronous one"""
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    q = asyncio.Queue(1)
    exception = None
    _END = object()

    async def yield_queue_items():
        while True:
            next_item = await q.get()
            if next_item is _END:
                break
            yield next_item
        if exception is not None:
            # the iterator has raised, propagate the exception
            raise exception

    def iter_to_queue():
        nonlocal exception
        try:
            for item in it:
                # This runs outside the event loop thread, so we
                # must use thread-safe API to talk to the queue.
                asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(q.put(item), loop).result()
        except Exception as e:
            exception = e
        finally:
            asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(q.put(_END), loop).result()

    threading.Thread(target=iter_to_queue).start()
    return yield_queue_items()
```

It can be tested with a trivial sync iterator that uses `time.time()` to block and an async heartbeat function to prove that the event loop is running:

```py
# async_wrap_iter definition as above

import time

def test_iter():
    for i in range(5):
        yield i
        time.sleep(1)

async def test():
    ait = async_wrap_iter(test_iter())
    async for i in ait:
        print(i)

async def heartbeat():
    while True:
        print('alive')
        await asyncio.sleep(.1)

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(heartbeat())
    await test()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Would the first approach avoid loading all items in memory ?

Comment: @YannickEinsweiler The second approach assumed that items would be processed faster than they would be extracted from the blocking iterator. I've now amended the answer to fix that by using a queue with fixed capacity and replacing `call_soon_threadsafe` with `run_coroutine_threadsafe` which provides back-pressure.

Comment: That did it ! Great.

Comment: I appreciate the solution. However one problem is that if the caller of `yield_queue_items` throws during the iteration, `iter_to_queue` will never end, since the put call will get stuck.

You need a way for `yield_queue_items` to signal to `iter_to_queue` whether it should proceed.

Comment: @ViniciusFortuna That's a general problem with iterators that refer to underlying resources, and would also happen on any abandoning of the iteration (`break` out of the loop), not just on exception. It's not trivial to fix, you can either use try/finally in `yield_queue_items()` to stop `iter_to_queue`, but then you're depending on GC's finalization. The other option is to return a context manager which must be entered for iteration to begin - then leaving the context manager can signal `iter_to_queue` to stop. If you post a question about that case, I can expand the code from this question.

Comment: @user4815162342 I am interested in this case using a context manager - is it still OK to ask this question?

Comment: @MindV0rtex I'm a bit out of shape regarding asyncio, but it would still make sense to ask the question, someone else could pick it up. Also, do take a look at the excellent aiostream library, I believe it already has the necessary context managers.